# How to reuse param on Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have the following function:

```
function Get-DBStatus
{
  <# .. removed help section for brevity .. #>
  [CmdletBinding()]
  [OutputType([System.Object])]
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$ServerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$ServerUser,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$ServerPassword,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$DatabaseName,
  )

  try
  {
    $params = @{ ... } # <<< It's possible to avoid this duplication ?
    $dbStatus = Invoke-SqlConnection @params
  }
  catch
  {
    Write-Error -Message ('An error has occured while ...')

  }
  ...
```

I would like to avoid the need to declare `@params` once my parameters were already declared and set. It's possible to do it with Powershell ?

Comment: You could use `$PsBoundParameters`.

Comment: @BenH is right,`Invoke-SqlConnection @PSBoundParameters`

Comment: @BenH, Please make it as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters that are passed in are saved in the automatic variable `$PSBoundParameters`. This can then be used by your command by splatting this variable with `@PSBoundParameters`.

```
function Get-DBStatus {
    <# .. removed help section for brevity .. #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Object])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ServerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ServerUser,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$ServerPassword,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$DatabaseName,
    )

try {
    $dbStatus = Invoke-SqlConnection @PSBoundParameters
}
catch {
    Write-Error -Message ('An error has occured while ...')
}
...
```